# How many processes and threads will be created?

Tags: multithreading, fork, pid

I have this code and trying to understand how many process and threads will be created from this:

```
pid t pid; 
pid = fork(); 
if (pid == 0) { /* child process */ 
 fork(); 
 thread create( . . .); 
} 
fork();
```

I think it creates 2 threads, from the fork inside the if loop. and 8 processes? But Im not sure if thats right

Comment: There is no loop. That is an "if".

Comment: why 8 processes? one of the `fork` calls is in the if test.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, there should be 8 threads and 6 processes.

Here's the diagrams to make it clear:

```
1) after first fork():

   |-------------------  child of p0 [p1]
---|-------------------  parent      [p0]

2) after second fork():

       |---------------  child of p1 [p2]
   |---|---------------              [p1]
---|-------------------              [p0]

3) after pthread_create():

            -----------  thread 1 of p2 [p2t1] 
       |---/-----------  thread 0 of p2 [p2t0]
       |    -----------  thread 1 of p1 [p1t1]
   |---|---/-----------  thread 0 of p1 [p1t0]
---|-------------------                 [p0]

4) after third fork():

         |------------ child of p2 [p5]
         |      ------             [p2t1]
       |-|-----/------             [p2t0]
       |   |---------- child of p1 [p4]
       |   |    ------             [p1t1]
   |---|---|---/------             [p1t0]
   |     |------------ child of p0 [p3]
---|-----|------------             [p0]
```

**important:** Remember that the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) call clones just the thread which executed it, thus process 4 [p4] has only one thread (same apply to process 5[p5]).

Comment: This question is taken from (as far as I can tell) _Operating System Concepts 9th Edition_, which states on page 183 that if "the separate process does not call exec() after forking, the separate process should duplicate all threads." This would mean there would be 10 threads. Is this inaccurate? It also states that "Some UNIX systems have chosen to have two versions of fork(), one that duplicates all threads and another that duplicates only the thread that invoked the fork() system call."

Comment: @Sammaron: See [this man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html).

Comment: Why there are 2 threads under p1 and p2 after pthread_create?

Answer (score 11):

One extra process will get created each time `fork` is called.

On first call to `fork`, parent process P creates sub-process SP1.
After fork, parent process calls `fork` again (skipping the `if`), creating sub-process SP2.

SP1 after fork calls `fork` inside `if`, creates sub-sub-process SSP1.
SP1 then spawns a thread.
SP1 leaves the `if`. and calls `fork` again, creating sub-sub-process SSP2.

SSP1 spawns a thread.
SSP1 leaves the `if`, and calls `fork`, creating sub-sub-sub-process SSSP.

So, processes created: SP1, SP2, SSP1, SSP2, SSSP = 5 processes.
If you count the original process P, there are 6 processes.

Only SP1 and SSP1 spawn threads, so there are 2 threads created. If you count all the main threads of all the processes, there are 7 or 8 threads, depending on whether or not you count the original process P.

An illustration of the processes and threads being created correlated to the code.

```
                         P
pid t pid;               |
pid = fork();            +------SP1
if (pid == 0) {          |      |
 fork();                 |      +---------------SSP1
 thread create(...);     |      |-SP1's thread  |-SSP1's thread
}                        |      |               |
fork();                  +-SP2  +-SSP2          +-SSSP
                         | |    | |             | |
```

Answer (score 3):

shouldn't it be 2 threads and 6 processes?

```
M
|  ↘
M     A
|     |↘
M     A*   B*
|     |    |
| ↘   | ↘  |↘
M   C A  D B  E
```

as I use * to represent thread.

Answer (score 0):

Total fork process is=5
Thread create is=2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).