# Clarifying a Q&A about multithreading

Tags: multithreading

While I was studying about multithreading I encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300830/how-many-processes-and-threads-will-be-created) question and answer.

The question is clear. But I do not understand why the answer is like that. Actually I do not understand whether processes are running concurrently or parent is waiting for the child processes to terminate.

Please explain this for me.

What I have thought so far:
After first fork we have two processes and two threads.
After second fork we have another process (and another thread)
After thread_create we have an extra thread.
After the last fork we have the last process duplicated. So we have another 2 threads and another process.

Result: we have 4 processes and 6 threads.

Answer (score 0):

> After thread_create we have an extra thread.

Clarification: in each process of the last fork since both parent and child calls thread_create, thus 2 extra threads.

> After the last fork we have the last process duplicated.

No, each previously existing processes (3) is split in halves here.

At the end we have 6 processes each represented by their respective threads and 2 extra threads created additionally.