# Execution of threads - Reason for output

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to run the following code. With the help of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300830/how-many-processes-and-threads-will-be-created), I am able to understand how many processes and threads shall be created but taking this a step further, I try to make threads execute a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *runner(void *param) {
    int i = atoi(param);    
    printf("My thread id is %ld\n",pthread_self());
    printf("\nValue of parameter = %d", i);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main() 
{
    int i = 5;
    pid_t pid;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pid = fork(); wait(NULL);

    if (pid == 0) { /* Child Process */

        fork(); wait(NULL);
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        i++;
        pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, &i);
        pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    } 
    fork(); wait(NULL);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this is:
My thread id is 139919964464896

Value of parameter = 0

Value of parameter = 0

My thread id is 139919964464896

Value of parameter = 0

Value of parameter = 0

Here, I am unable to figure out:

1. Why the line **My thread id is 139919964464896** gets printed twice whereas the line **Value of parameter = 0** gets printed four times.
2. Why does the value print as 0 when the passed parameter has been initialized to 5 and incremented to 6?

Please, could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the line My thread id is 139919964464896 gets printed twice
>   whereas the line Value of parameter = 0 gets printed four times.

When you `fork()`, each process gets the copy of the buffer from parent too (among all other things). Typically `stdout` (standard output) is line buffered. That means the buffer will be flushed either when you print a newline (`\n`) or flush the buffer explicitly i.e. calling `fflush(stdout);`
When you call `fork()` for the first time, there was nothing in the buffer (i.e. you haven't printed anything so far). So it makes no difference. But when you call `fork()` the second time, the entire buffer that wasn't flushed gets copied to child process. When the process it exits, both processes flush their buffer. Thus the `Value of parameter = 0` is printed twice.

But  line`My thread id is ....` is *not* printed twice because the `\n` forces the buffer to be flushed.

So either add a newline at the end:

```
printf("\nValue of parameter = %d\n", i);
                                 ^ forces flushing the output buffer
```

Or call `fflush(stdout);` before calling `fork()` for the second time.

Obviously after the first fork, you have two processes and both of them will create one thread each. So you'll see output from two threads.

Comment: I just started reading Operating Systems and this was a lot of useful information. Thanks a lot for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your bug is in how you are interpreting the thread argument here:

```
int i = atoi(param);
```

The value of param is "&i" from the "main()" function, so param is really an `int*` object that has been converted to a `void*` pointer. However, with "atoi", you are treating it as if it were a string.

Replace that line with:

```
int* typed_param = (int*) param;
int i = *typed_param;
```

And then things should make sense.

Comment: Thanks for correction. Please could you also assist me with the first point, why id of thread prints twice and value of param 4 times?