# thread_create(): member of which C library

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

I am trying to build by gcc a simple C code using thread_create. To use thread_create(), which library should be "#include"d? Should I send also specific flags to the gcc?

Comment: Do you mean [C11 thrd_create](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_create) defined in `<thread.h>` or [POSIX pthread_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_create.html) defined in `<pthread.h>`?

Comment: @AlterMann I am referring to the function mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300830/how-many-processes-and-threads-will-be-created and in the book Operating System Concepts by Silberschatz et al.

Comment: Should I send also specific flags to the gcc?. Yes. -lpthread has to be used for compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pthread_create` included in `<pthread.h>`, for more information, see the manpage of `pthread_create`, if you're on Linux you can type `man pthread_create` in your terminal.